# BizTalk development with VS2012 without Server installation

Tags: visual-studio-2012, biztalk

I have already BizTalk 2013 server installed on cloud. And I have already Visual Studio 2012 on my Window 7 computer. What do I need to install (and where do I get it)  to have Visual Studio 2012 BizTalk 2013 projects without installing BizTalk server on my machine.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For development you must install the BizTalk Developer Tools from the BizTalk install media.  That adds the BizTalk Project System to Visual Studio.

However, while such a setup is technically possible, you will find it frustratingly unproductive.

Mostly because you will not be able to Deploy directly to the remote BizTalk Server.

If you are serious about BizTalk development, please consider either a VM with the entire stack (Windows, SQL Server, BizTalk Server and Visual Studio) or boot to VHD also with the entire stack.  If you use Windows 8 ENT, you can use the same VHD either in a VM or direct boot.

Comment: So I have to install complet server and SDK to push my application to cloud based Biztalk server later on.? Thank you

Comment: To effectively develop you app, yes.  Deployment to a BizTalk VM on Azure is no different than on-prem BizTalk.